# Is there an extra virgin olive brand produced in Spain, called "Clorlina"?

Tags: olive-oil

Is there an extra virgin olive brand produced in Spain, called "Clorlina"? Its barcode is 8436544133904, and I heard 84* means production in Spain.

I have searched for "Clorlina" in Bing, with or without "olive oil", but only found it is an olive oil brand being sold in China (for example, [here](https://detail.youzan.com/show/goods?from_source=gbox_seo&alias=3645ud2o14nme)). The link says that the brand was founded by a prestigious company named Aires deJaen, by a noble family named Lopez, in Jaén, Andalucia, Spain.

Internet access from China is very restricted, so I am not sure if I got the necessary information.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, that article number [is registered](https://gepir.gs1.org/index.php/search-by-gtin) to a Spanish olive oil bottling company, [whose website](https://www.airesdejaen.com/) is available in Spanish, English, Chinese and Japanese. So this *might* be a product of that company specifically designed for the Chinese market.

Comment: And the article number prefix (= the GS1 country code) does not make any claim about where the product was produced. It just tells you the country of the GS1 member organization where the company registered their "GS1 company prefix".

Comment: re: "84" means something; false. The outer 8 is a checksum digit that depends on both sides of the barcode's digits, it won't even be the same for two similar products from the same manufacturer. The left side of a UPC is the manufacturer ID and the right side is a product/size ID...

Comment: @dandavis, according to the EAN specification, the last digit is the checksum, not the first. There is no requirement for the placement of the human readable digits, but the first digit is frequently placed outside partly to keep the other two sets of numbers equal length and partly to indicate the approximate width of the left quiet zone. (a `>` is often appended to the other side of the barcode to indicate the width of the right quiet zone.) A nice little summary of the data format can be found [here](https://softmatic.com/barcode-ean-13.html#ean-data).

Answer (score 19):

No, there is no such olive oil brand in Spain, nor would there be.  The word "chlorlina" in Spanish is almost identical to the word for "chlorine".  Nobody would name their olive oil that.

This is certainly a China-only brand.  It may be made up of low-quality olive oils (or other oils) from random locations.  It could also be real olive oil from [Aires de Jaen](https://www.airesdejaen.com/exportar-aceite-de-oliva/), who notes on their web page that they export to China.  There's no real way to tell, unless you can personally distinguish quality olive oil by taste.

(added extra info from @L.Dutch per comments below)

Comment: Thanks. It is very clueless for me to find affordable olive oil here. Many of native products are tasted like soy oil, and one or two are twice as expensive as imported ones.

Comment: The web page of [Aires de Jaen](https://www.airesdejaen.com/exportar-aceite-de-oliva/) mentions that they do export in China, though it doesn't mention the brand under which they do it. It has even a Chinese version of their site.

Comment: Well, `clorlina` does not really exists: https://dle.rae.es/clorlina?m=form, but yes, it sounds like something you use for disinfecting swimming pools ;-), so there is no chance to use it for something edible...

Comment: @L.Dutch Do you find their extra virgin olive oil legitimate? anything suspicious?

Comment: https://www.airesdejaen.com/zh-hant/%e5%b0%8e%e5%87%ba/ - potentially legitimate - it looks like Aires de Jaen partners with people to create their own brands, so it could be someone importing under a brand they made up called "Clorlina" - but, yeah, I can't find any mention of it either.

Comment: @FuzzyChef Why is the product likely to be low-quality and contain oils from random locations? I feel this is unfounded unless explained clearly.

Comment: @AravindhKrishnamoorthy China has fairly lax laws concerning food production, so it is very common that expensive food items are adulterated with cheaper ones or made entirely of cheaper items. Olive oil would be one such expensive food item that is likely not genuine. Same with, for example, [honey](https://www.insider.com/fake-honey-problems-how-it-works-2020-9).

Comment: @AravindhKrishnamoorthy adulteration and outright fraud is rife in the olive oil industry; most of the EV olive oil sold worldwide is fake. The reason I say "probably" here is that if the olive oil is being sold under a made-up name, then it's fairly likely that other things about the oil are fraudulent as well.

Comment: @L.Dutch well spotted!  Do you want to post that as a contrasting answer?

Comment: I think it's at most an integration to this answer

Comment: OK, added to the answer then.

Answer (score 7):

The Spanish Language Stack Exchange has a question and an [answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/42225) about this same question. According to the answer this is a case of the name "Gloria" being transliterated into Hanzi as 歌洛琳娜 (Gē luò lín nà) and then this is transliterated back into Latin script as "Clorlina". I don't speak Spanish or Chinese myself so I can't confirm whether this is correct or not.

Comment: It sounds vaguely plausible, but... the bottle has plenty of text that tries to look like Spanish. Would they really change the _name_ while keeping the rest of the text "Spanish" if this were legitimate?

Comment: @Luaan I can't say for certain but it's possible that the text is just machine translated from Chinese to Spanish which can work mostly OK but fail on trickier parts. At least Google Translate translates "歌洛琳娜" as "Gloria" but maybe some other machine translation system gives a different result.

Answer (score 6):

As a Spanish speaker I was surprised by this post, no one would name their olive oil "Chlorine" and the Spanish search results on Duckduckgo show nothing except the page you attached [image: ddg results for "aceite de oliva clorlina"]

Comment: Thanks. I think no one here bothers to figure out the meaning of the word. As long as it is from Spain, it is probably legitimate.

Comment: considering the Chinese law enforcement problem with "gutter oil," I might take some comfort in an oil with chlorine in it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutter_oil

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "Glorlina" brand in Spain for olive oil. It is only a brand used for export.

歌洛琳娜橄榄油产自西班牙安达卢西亚的哈恩地区

It says exactly, “Glorena” olive oil is produced in the Jaen region of Andalusia, Spain.”

Glorlina is a poor translation of 歌洛琳娜 (Glorena). Glorena is a woman's name, although uncommon, but existing in the Spanish language. Example - Glorena Castillo, Glorena García…

Comment: It could also be a poor translation of Gloria, as noted in an older answer.